# What causes "missed method" in this code #2?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, game-center

I have the same problem as in this thread: [What causes "Missed Method" in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323244/what-causes-missed-method-in-this-code)

but i do not understand how to solve this or if it even is a problem.

I am doing the tutorial in the book "Beginning iOS Game Center and Game Kit" and get this problem. I do get "...Missed Method" all the time and is trying to understand why, unfortunately i do not. I also tried to use the answer on the thread above but to no avail.

I would very much appreciate some help on this one.

The code i am using currently:

```
#import "GameCenterManager.h"

@implementation GameCenterManager

@synthesize delegate;

+(BOOL)isGameCenterAvailable {
Class gcClass = (NSClassFromString(@"GKLocalPlayer"));

NSString *reqSysVer = @"4.1";
NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion];

BOOL osVersionSupported = ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending);

return (gcClass && osVersionSupported);
}

-(void)retrieveFriendsList {

if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated == YES) {
    [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer]loadFriendsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *friends, NSError *error) {
        [self callDelegateOnMainThread:@selector(friendsFinishLoading:error:) withArg:friends error:error];
    }];
} else {
    NSLog(@"...You must authenticate first");
}
}

-(void)authenticateLocalUser {

if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated) {
    return;
}

[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){
    [self callDelegateOnMainThread:@selector(processGameCenterAuthentication:) withArg:NULL error: error];
}];
}

-(void)callDelegateOnMainThread:(SEL)selector withArg: (id) arg error:(NSError*) err {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
    [self callDelegate:selector withArg: arg error: err];
});
}

-(void)callDelegate: (SEL) selector withArg: (id) arg error: (NSError*) err {
assert([NSThread isMainThread]);

if ([delegate respondsToSelector: selector]) {
    if(arg != NULL) {
        [delegate performSelector: selector withObject: arg withObject: err];

    } else {
        [delegate performSelector: selector withObject: err];
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"...Missed Method");
}
}
```

Output, after GC authorization:

```
...Missed Method
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code calls `[self callDelegateOnMainThread:@selector(processGameCenterAuthentication:) withArg:NULL error: error];` which ends up in a method (`callDelegate:withArg:error:`) that checks wether your class implemented the `processGameCenterAuthentication:` method. You get the `Missed Method` output because you don't seem to have implemented it.

Comment: I do call the method, however i did find that the method is executed twice and it is the second time it "...Misses Method".

Comment: I did find the problem, it was a misspell in the selector calling "friendsFinishedLoading" i had (in the code above) "friendsFinishLoading". I am such a n00b :-(  ...however a BIG thank you JustSid for leading me on the correct track.